# Django admin how unlock your own account?

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django admin I have by mistake locked myself by attempting the wrong password.
I later of deleted the user and created another one using manage.py createsuperuser. However, it still says that I'm locked. How do I unlock myself?

It gives the following error when I try to log in using Django admin..

Account locked: too many login attempts. Contact an admin to unlock your account.

Comment: There is nothing in django by default that will lock an account so what exactly are you using?

Comment: Django-admin when you try to log in.. I by mistake entered the wrong password by trying 3 different ones. I later deleted the user and created another one using manage.py createsuperuser but it's still not working

Comment: There is *nothing* in django by default that will lock an account

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given your error message and 3 strike policy, I assume you have django-axes in your project. You may have it configured to block by IP, regardless of user. That would explain why creating a new user did not work.

[Djang-axes documentation](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3_usage.html#resetting-attempts-and-lockouts) gives you an outline of how to clear lockouts.

> `manage.py axes_reset` will reset all lockouts and access records.

If you are currently in production and do not want to risk resetting any valid lockouts, you could try resetting for just your ip

> `manage.py axes_reset ip will clear lockout/records for ip`

So, for example on if you are logged in on the same computer your server is on, you can use localhost:
`manage.py axes_reset ip 127.0.0.1`

If for some reason that doesn't work, you still have the option of manually deleting your `AccessAttempt` from your database. This assumes, of course, that you have access to your database, that your user has delete privileges, you are comfortable with sql, and you have not changed the default table name from django-axes.

`delete from axes_accessattempt where username ='your_username';` where 'your_username' is the account you wish to unlock.

This can also by done by ip:
`delete from axes_accessattempt where ip_address='your_ip';` where 'your_ip' is the ip address from the computer you are using.

Comment: The link provide to Django Axes has changed: https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3_usage.html#resetting-attempts-and-lockouts

Comment: @Erri Updated the link in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

***Resetting attempts from command line:***

1. `python manage.py axes_reset`
   will reset all lockouts and access records.
2. `python manage.py axes_reset_ip [ip ...]`
   will clear lockouts and records for the given IP addresses.
3. `python manage.py axes_reset_username [username ...]`
   will clear lockouts and records for the given usernames.
4. `python manage.py axes_reset_logs (age)`
   will reset (i.e. delete) AccessLog records that are older than the given age where the default is 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

Yep here's how I did it.. Go to the shell using `python manage.py shell`
There enter the following commands

```
from axes.models import AccessAttempt
AccessAttempt.objects.all().delete()
```

If however the data is needed you must then delete only the object containing your username by

```
for obj in AccessAttempt.objects.all():
    if obj.username == your_username:
        obj.delete()
```